# Python 3 script to upload a file to a REST URL (multipart request)

Tags: python, rest, python-3.x, multipart

I am fairly new to Python and using Python 3.2. I am trying to write a python script that will pick a file from user machine (such as an image file) and submit it to a server using REST based invocation. The Python script should invoke a REST URL and submit the file when the script is called.

This is similar to multipart POST that is done by browser when uploading a file; but here I want to do it through Python script.

If possible do not want to add any external libraries to Python and would like to keep it fairly simple python script using the core Python install.

Can some one guide me? or share some script example that achieve what I want?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian : I have already tried [link](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/146306/) but could not make it work. As I said I am newbie to Python and come from a Java background. I realized that I may not be using the correct libraries required. I will try what you suggested.

Comment: Requests now supports Python 3.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Requests library is what you need. You can install with `pip install requests`.

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

```
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
>>> files = {'file': open('report.xls', 'rb')}
>>> r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

Comment: No specific reason for 3.2. Being new to Python I decide to get the latest release and did not give much thought the aspects you mentioned. I had seen the MultipartPostHandler before but it did not work because I could not install the .egg file. Is there a different way to install .egg in 3.2?  anyway ... let me try with 2.7.

Comment: "install .egg in 3.2" you should wait for a port. it depends on urllib2 which (AFAIK, cant substantiate this!) is not forward compatible with Python 3.

Comment: Although both the post were helpful this is more close to my requirements. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Requests now supports Python 3.

Comment: Thanks and It worked for single file. How about multiple files?

Comment: @Arockia I would try MultipartEncoder from requests_toolbelt or even uploading in a loop

Answer (score 5):

A RESTful way to upload an image would be to use `PUT` request if you know what the image url is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import http.client 

h = http.client.HTTPConnection('example.com')
h.request('PUT', '/file/pic.jpg', open('pic.jpg', 'rb'))
print(h.getresponse().read())
```

[upload_docs.py](https://bitbucket.org/tarek/distribute/src/427241027bb8/setuptools/command/upload_docs.py#cl-89) contains an example how to upload a file as `multipart/form-data` with basic http authentication. It supports both Python 2.x and Python 3.

You could use also [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/#install) to post files as a `multipart/form-data`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests

response = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post',
                         files={'file': open('filename','rb')})
print(response.content)
```

Comment: Requests now supports Python 3.

Comment: Is this solution only for python 3? I am working on python 2.7 and will let you know!

Comment: @tilaprimera: the question has [tag:python-3.x] tag therefore the answer is for Python 3 but almost the same code works on Python 2 too (just change the import in the first code example).

Comment: Is it done the same way if I am doing request.PUT on an mp3 file?

Comment: @tilaprimera: yes. You could also use `Content-Type` if your server supports it (so that you wouldn't put an mp3 file using an url for an image).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use unirest . Sample code

```
import unirest

# consume async post request
def consumePOSTRequestSync():
 params = {'test1':'param1','test2':'param2'}

 # we need to pass a dummy variable which is open method
 # actually unirest does not provide variable to shift between
 # application-x-www-form-urlencoded and
 # multipart/form-data
 params['dummy'] = open('dummy.txt', 'r')
 url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
 headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}
 # call get service with headers and params
 response = unirest.post(url, headers = headers,params = params)
 print "code:"+ str(response.code)
 print "******************"
 print "headers:"+ str(response.headers)
 print "******************"
 print "body:"+ str(response.body)
 print "******************"
 print "raw_body:"+ str(response.raw_body)

# post sync request multipart/form-data
consumePOSTRequestSync()
```

You can check out this post http://stackandqueue.com/?p=57 for more details