# Uploading binary file to API using python

Tags: rest, python-requests, zfs

I am trying to upload a package binary over to the RestAPI of storage using python. But it keeps throwing error and couldn't upload the file. 
Below is the code I am using to achieve it :

```
jsonheaderup={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'}

file = open('install.pkg.gz', 'rb')
files = {'file': file}

def upload_code():

  u = requests.post("%s/api/sys/v2/updates" % (url), files=files, verify=False,      headers=jsonheaderup)
  l = json.loads(u.text)

upload_code()
```

Comment: I tried to change the jsonheader file type to application/x-gzip . But now it gives an argument error, even though everything is present : 

Error :
`{u'fault': {u'message': u'required input argument is missing (upload)', u'code': 400, u'name': u'ERR_MISSING_ARG'}}`

Comment: Just wondering ... Why the `zfs` tag?

Comment: And BTW, if you have more info, like your first comment, you can edit your original post to include it.

Comment: zfs tag as I am trying to access the RestAPI of a ZFSSA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The earlier posts didn't really helped but I figured it out by referring the original doc of **requests**: Streaming uploads. Check [doc here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/).

As my file was huge around 1.9 GB, so session was breaking in between the upload process, hence giving error as "Internal error".

As its huge file I streamed and upload it by providing a file-like object in my function:

```
def upload_code():
  jsonheaderup={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'}
  with open('/root/ak-nas-2013-06-05-7-18-1-1-3-nd.pkg.gz', 'rb') as file:
    requests.post("%s/api/system/v1/updates" % (url), data=file, auth=zfsauth, verify=False, headers=jsonheaderup, timeout=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I can not see any mistake.

Did you see this: [Python 3 script to upload a file to a REST URL (multipart request)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061775/python-3-script-to-upload-a-file-to-a-rest-url-multipart-request) ?